# MySQL - Delete with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a database with properties and I need to delete all the properties except for those "owned" by either one of 3 "Inscription Agents". Each property can have up to 2 "owners": `agent_inscripteur_1` and `agent_inscripteur_2` on the database.
This is my code:

```
DELETE FROM inscriptions 
WHERE (agent_inscripteur_1 != 100520 OR agent_inscripteur_2 != 100520) 
      AND (agent_inscripteur_1 != 97927 OR agent_inscripteur_2 != 97927) 
      AND (agent_inscripteur_1 != 99237 OR agent_inscripteur_2 != 99237)
```

I think what is happening in my case is that the first part of the code before the `AND` is executed before the rest, so all properties except for those listed by the first agent are being deleted (by the time it gets to the second and third agent, the properties are all gone).

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, in SQL the db has no concept of "first" for Boolean conditions (`CASE` is an exception for a couple of reasons...).  Since for each row at least one of the sub-conditions will (likely) be true, the row is deleted.  DBs do this for a couple of reasons: 1) it's actually due to dbs thinking in "sets", essentially matching records 2) it allows the db to choose which condition to evaluate first, allowing queries to be faster.

Comment: Thanks for making this clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you simply change your condition like below using `NOT IN` instead

```
DELETE FROM inscriptions 
WHERE agent_inscripteur_1 NOT IN (100520,97927,99237)
OR agent_inscripteur_2 NOT IN (100520,97927,99237)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this deletes 0 rows.

Comment: @PalmerDelCampo, change the `AND` to `OR`. Most probably the condition is not matching. See edit.

Comment: That works, thanks. Please edit your answer to "or" and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this,

```
DELETE FROM inscriptions 
WHERE ( 
(agent_inscripteur_1 != 100520 AND agent_inscripteur_2 != 100520) 
OR (agent_inscripteur_1 != 97927 AND agent_inscripteur_2 != 97927)
OR (agent_inscripteur_1 != 99237 AND agent_inscripteur_2 != 99237)
)
```

Comment: No, this will still delete records he wants to keep.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use here not in operator

```
DELETE FROM inscriptions WHERE agent_inscripteur_1 not in(100520,97927,99237) 
OR 
agent_inscripteur_2 not in(100520,97927,99237)
```

Comment: Thanks but this deletes 0 rows as well. Bump.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the simplest approach when attempting to use negative logic is to write the inverse and then prefix with not. Identify the records of concern and then do not delete them, something like this

```
DELETE FROM inscriptions 
WHERE not ( (agent_inscripteur_1 = 100520 OR agent_inscripteur_2 = 100520) 
      or (agent_inscripteur_1 = 97927 OR agent_inscripteur_2 = 97927) 
      or (agent_inscripteur_1 = 99237 OR agent_inscripteur_2 = 99237))
```

You could simplify the query to something like this

```
DELETE FROM inscriptions 
WHERE not (   agent_inscripteur_1 in (100520, 97927, 99237) 
           OR agent_inscripteur_2 in (100520, 97927, 99237) 
           )
```